# anchor tag text over flow from div box

Tags: html, css, overflow

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test_link_is_soooo_long</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
div {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 150px;
}
a {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
```

link text goes outside border and i want to fix it. But not get any solution.

[result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCDyY.png)

how I fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use text ellipsis.if you dont want to increase the width of the div and display the link in a single line.The part going out of the with will be displayed as three dots

```css
div {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 150px;
}
a { 
      width: 100px;
      display:inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test_link_is_soooo_long</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: or maybe you can set (increase) the width of `<div>` in order to display the whole text.

Comment: @YashKaranke Sure.But there was an effort to do the elipssis in the code.I pointed that in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I got my answer.

Comment: @DipendraGhatal Please accept or upvote if it helped